# scrolling div within a container div not working

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow, containers

I know there is a lot of examples/help of this specific CSS technique, but I feel that my code is 100% correct, still however, I'm not sure why it isn't working.

The point is, im trying to have an inner div wrapped by an outer div.
I want the inner div to scroll vertically without a scroll bar appearing, and I don't want the contents of the inner div to flow outwards outside of the outer div.

Here is the jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/FE5X7/

Here it is live on my domain: [paxframe.com](http://paxframe.com)

The HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="author" content="" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css"  />

<title>Bryan the Lion</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id ="wrapper">
        <div id = "header">

        </div>
        <div id ="wrapper_main">
        <p>main wrapper</p>
            <div id = "main">
                <p>main div</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The CSS:

```
body{
height: 100%;
}
@font-face {
font-family: "AlexBrush";
src: url(fonts/AlexBrush-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
}
#wrapper{
width: 80% ;
margin: 0 auto ;
background: yellow ;
height: 100% ;  

}
#wrapper_main{
background: red ;   
margin: 0 auto ;
width: 700px ;
height: 500px ;
border: solid 1px black ;
overflow: hidden;
}
#main{
background: blue ;
width: 700px ;
height: 1000px ;
overflow: scroll;

}
#header{
width: 90% ;
height: 10px ;
background: green ;
}
#header h1{
font-family: AlexBrush ;
font-size: 5em ;
}
#nav{
height: 50px ;
width: 80% ;
margin: 0 auto ;
display: block ;
background: gray ;
}   
#nav ul li{
display: inline-block;
letter-spacing: 2px ;
background: purple ;
}
#sidebar{

}
```

Comment: The text within that scrolling div needs to go so far down that it will begin the scrolling. Test it by adding a whole bunch of text or line break, or even images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that withoud any child element that will overflow your div. Try adding some lipsum text to your div and it will work.

---

You are giving overflow:scroll to the wrong element.

Change:

```
#wrapper_main{
    background: red ;   
    margin: 0 auto ;
    width: 700px ;
    height: 500px ;
    border: solid 1px black ;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#main{
    background: blue ;
    width: 700px;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

Updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/FE5X7/2/

Update:

```
#wrapper_main::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

New fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/FE5X7/3/

Note: works with webkit browsers. You will need jquery for hiding scrollbar for moz and ie.

Comment: I want the scroll bar to disappear

Comment: I know there is another way, by wrapping the div in a container, do yuo know which method im talking about?

Comment: You can't do that withoud any child element that will overflow your div. Try adding some lipsum text to your div and it will work.

Comment: Yes Canser, you were right on that, put it as an answer so I could choose it and upvote.

Comment: @BryanFajardo Just edited my answer bro. You can accept it. :)